# Cannot access OpenVAS following installation

Tags: openvas

I am sure that once I find the issue I am going to feel like a fool, but I have been pouring highlevel debugging into something that I know the answer must be right there.
Same issue on 2 different 'new' CentOS machines, I install OpenVAS, run openvas-check-setup --server a whole bunch of times, follow the instructions till error free, the ports light up but I cannot connect.

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9390                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9391                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9392              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9393              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9329              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
```

I see the packets hit the server just fine:

```
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
10:32:27.119370 IP 10.20.10.47.ds-user > 10.180.10.51.9392: Flags [S], seq 2713892558, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
10:32:27.381288 IP 10.20.10.47.ds-mail > 10.180.10.51.9392: Flags [S], seq 2903829103, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
```

But the server never replies:

It's not a firewall:

```
[root@offtbn ~]# iptables-save
[root@offtbn ~]#
```

Firewall is empty

I tried all of the OpenVAS ports using http: and https: in every different browser and from multiple machines.
The first OpenVAS server 'did' work for a day, but something changed which is why I built the second machine from scratch. Both have the exact same issue and the exact same symptoms.

```
/etc/rc.d/init.d/openvas-administrator restart
/etc/rc.d/init.d/openvas-manager restart
/etc/rc.d/init.d/openvas-scanner restart
```

all run clean
I am really stumped on this one.

Comment: [root@offtbnewsnort ~]# omp -h 10.180.10.51 -p 9390 -u admin -w admin -T -v

WARNING: Verbose mode may reveal passwords!

Will try to connect to host 10.180.10.51, port 9390...

(omp:18817): lib  serv-WARNING **: Failed to connect to server
Failed to acquire socket.
[root@offtbnewsnort ~]# omp -h 10.180.10.51 -p 9392 -u admin -w admin -T -v
WARNING: Verbose mode may reveal passwords!
Will try to connect to host 10.180.10.51, port 9392...
(omp:18825): lib  serv-WARNING **: Failed to connect to server
Failed to acquire socket.

Comment: openvas is just trashware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the site was having network issues.
From what I could tell, a proxy was breaking headers and somehow this exterior failure was effecting openvas's ability to do a basic login.
Did an install on a different network with the exact same distro and everything went flawless.
Not exactly sure the exact cause.